# can I use .split() with csv.reader?

Tags: python

I want to create a dictionary based off of csv 1st column as key.  can i use .split() to do this or will csv.dictreader automatically base key off of 1st column?

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
import sys

#import csv file and store in dictionary
dict=defaultdict(list)
file=csv.reader(open(‘sys.argv[1]’,‘rt’))
    for f in file:
        a,b,c,d=f.split()
        dict[a].append((b,c,d))
file.close()
```

Comment: If by "column" you mean "row" then the dictreader can already do that

Answer (score 3):

`csv.reader` should already split your rows up based on the delimiter you specify. So something like this:

```
csv_file = csv.reader(open(filename, "rb"), delimiter=",")
for row in csv_file:
    print row
```

will give you this:

```
["an element", "another element", "a third element"]
["an element", "another element", "a third element"]
["an element", "another element", "a third element"]
   ....
```

You shouldn't have to do `row.split()`.

A couple more things:

1) Don't overwrite python built-in names. `file` is a python builtin (as is `dict`). Call your reader `csv_file` or something (and rename your dictionary too).

2) Unless you plan on using the `defaultdict` capabilities later in your script, all you need is a good old regular `dict`

3) There's no need to unpack the contents of `f` twice in the first place. You're making this into a 2 step process when it only needs one:

*implemented*

```
myDict = {}
for row in csv_file:
    myDict[row[0]] = row[1:]
```